# How can I include location data in a page so that Google search results include a map?

Tags: seo, google

I'd like to include extra information that would give us a bump in location specific search?

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't seem Google has figured out your location [on its own](http://www.google.com/support/places/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=28247)(see "How it works"), you should set up a Places listing yourself. Either way, this will give you more control over the data they have on hand for your business. This [SEOMoz post from](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-googles-new-local-serp-affected-your-ranking-11360) November does some digging into the effects of filling out the listing and also how some of the information is used.